# sofware which document all JSX attributes but with narrowed type

Tags: typescript

## (1) Purpose

> I am trying to create software which will document all `JSX` attributes of file with their narrowed typescript type.

#### Input file:

> `test` attribute of `div` is defined as `{test:'hello'}` so accept only `hello` word as `string`

```
const testAsConst = 'hello' as const;

const test = 'hello';

// both variables above works
<div test={test} />;
```

Expected output: `[ [ 'test', '"hello"' ] ]`

### (2) but

without `as const` the output is `[ [ 'test', 'string' ] ]`

with `as const` the output is `[ [ 'test', '"hello"' ] ]`

> This `but` chapter is quite obvious. I know what `as const` did. But can this example work without `as const` because without that typescript reports no-errors so it is `hello` and not `string` without `as const`... I hope you understand.

#### software source code which produce output

```
import typescript from 'typescript';

const program = typescript.createProgram(['inputFile.tsx'], { target: typescript.ScriptTarget.ESNext });

const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();

for (const sourceFile of program.getSourceFiles()) {
  if (!sourceFile.isDeclarationFile) {
    const output = visit(sourceFile);

    console.log(output);
  }
}

function visit(node: typescript.Node, output2: [string, string][] = []): [string, string][] | undefined {
  if (typescript.isJsxAttribute(node)) {
    const attributeName = node.name.text;

    const symbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(node.name);

    if (symbol) {
      const type = typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, symbol.valueDeclaration!);

      output2.push([attributeName, typeChecker.typeToString(type)]);
    }
  }

  typescript.forEachChild(node, node2 => {
    visit(node2, output2);
  });

  return output2;
}
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding the question.
What do you get as an output if you `const testAsConst: string = 'hello' `